# How to Return a Custom Objective-C Object from a Class Method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays

I have a set of Objective-C files in my app labeled Crop.h/Crop.m. Inside is a custom array of different vegetables from a video game - each vegetable has properties like a name, growing season, number of days to grow, etc.

I need to write a function which loops through this array and checks each Crop name value to see if it matches with my view title (self.title). Below is an example of two crop objects:

```
Crop *turnip = [[Crop alloc] init];
[turnip setName:@"Turnip"];
[turnip setSeason:@"Spring"];
[turnip setBagPrice:120];
[turnip setSaleValue:60];
[turnip setDaysToGrow:5];
[turnip setRenewableDays:0];

Crop *potato = [[Crop alloc] init];
[potato setName:@"Potato"];
[potato setSeason:@"Spring"];
[potato setBagPrice:150];
[potato setSaleValue:80];
[potato setDaysToGrow:8];
[potato setRenewableDays:0];
```

Then what I'm thinking is calling a new class function titled **returnCropData:** which takes the self.title as a parameter. I'm just not sure if this is my best method... I'd appreciate any suggestions from iOS devs.

Here's the simple class method I have so far - no data matching yet as I'm still trying to figure out which loop would be best. I'm also struggling to figure out the syntax to add an NSString parameter onto the function

```
+ (Crop *)returnCropData
{
    Crop *turnip = [[Crop alloc] init];
    [turnip setName:@"Turnip"];
    [turnip setSeason:@"Spring"];
    [turnip setBagPrice:120];
    [turnip setSaleValue:60];
    [turnip setDaysToGrow:5];
    [turnip setRenewableDays:0];

    // more crops here....

    NSMutableArray *cropListing = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [cropListing addObject:turnip];
    [cropListing addObject:potato];
    // add the other crops here...

    return potato; 
    // return any Crop value for now
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear... Are you asking for help on how to create a function that returns a specific Crop object based on the string you pass it?

Comment: @yAak yes absolutely! So for example pass in the string "Potato" and this function will return the entire potato Crop object. The matching would be against the crop's `name` property (created using `setName`). I know it's a bit confusing.. please let me know if there's anything specific I can clarify in the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's Objective-C docs recommend you use `objectWithParams:` grammar for class methods (constructors). So in your case, you should change your existing method name to

`+ (Crop *)cropWithName:(NSString *)name`

And call it with `Crop *turnip = [Crop cropWithName:@"Turnip];`

and then in your for loop you can check if the passed in name equals the name of your object with `[name isEqualToString:turnip.name]`.

This will work, however it seems as though every time that method is called you're creating a ton of Crop objects - time intensive on your part, and memory intensive on the device. Instead, you should look into making a plist file that uses a dictionary to represent each kind of Crop, and then in your creation method you can use your passed in name to look up all the other information about the specified crop. Then you can just return one instance of Crop instead of instantiating a massive amount.

Here's a link to Apple documentation that explains plists:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html

Specifically, in any objects that I want to pull from a plist I define the following method that takes values from a dictionary and sets an object's properties:

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    self = [super init];

    [self setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dictionary];

    return self;
}
```

And then in a class where I want to access an array of data, I would create a synthesized  @property and then define this method (in this case, I've got Song objects):

```
- (NSMutableArray *)songs
{
    if (_songs == nil)
    {
        NSArray *songDicts = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ChillMix" ofType:@"plist"]];

        _songs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[songDicts count]];


        // Fast enumeration //
        for (NSDictionary *currDict in songDicts)
        {
            Song *song = [[Song alloc] initWithDictionary:currDict];
            [_songs addObject:song];
        }
    }
    return _songs;
}
```

Here is a sample project I've developed: https://github.com/Jlawr3nc3/MusicLibraryiOS

`[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:]` should be your new best friend. It's awesome. If you can format your XML in plist format, you're down to one. single. line. to parse data. (PS normal XML is annoying as hell to parse on iOS so this is a huge time save if you can avoid straight up XML).

Also, I'm not sure what the use case would be for creating a crop object based on a view's title. Since you're already aware of the name of the crop before the view is instantiated, you could create a Crop object and set a Crop property of the view to the crop object you created, and then in viewDidLoad just do `self.title = self.crop.name;`. Finally, if you've got a `UITableView` of crop objects you shouldn't populate the table view with static text; instead populate it with objects you create from a plist, and then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you can do `[self.arrayOfCrops objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` to get the object you tapped on, and pass it in with the view you load. Anyway, check out Apple's sample code for more info on plists and tableviews etc, 'cause they've got a lot of information on this exact stuff.

Comment: Yes I think you are right Jack, thank you! Do you have any resources from SO or other articles on building such a plist? I'm generally new to setting up model objects, I wasn't sure what the best method would be so I just created one big class file. I do agree that it's intensive to instantiate all these objects at once - I knew there had to be a better solution! I was considering XML but that seems worse.. I'll google around a bit for a plist code example

Comment: Also I had no idea about the `ObjectWithParams:param` syntax on constructors - so another big thank you for turning me onto that.

Comment: You're welcome! Check out Apple's sample code at http://developer.apple.com because they talk about this exact sort of thing. I'll check as well and get back to you with some links. And yeah Apple's grammar is awesome. I'd never think about doing it that way but as soon as I found out about it, I realized it makes a ton of sense and produces more readable code.

Comment: @JakeRocheleau Property List Documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @JackLawrence this is fantastic man thank you. I just finished converting my initialized crop objects into [this plist format](http://f.cl.ly/items/0M2x2f190I2H3f331B0T/crops-plist.jpg) which looks basically the same. My concern now is my Crop.h/Crop.m Object files may be worthless? Do I still need to define each property like `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;` in the header and implement them using `@synthesize name, season, bagPrice, saleValue, daysToGrow, renewableDays;` ?

Comment: @JackLawrence I'll try to follow through with all the edits you added here. If I'm having troubles I'll just open a new question and link to it from this comment thread - it may be easier for you to answer with more space :] sincerely thank you for pointing me in the right direction this has helped a ton.

Comment: @JackLawrence oh and I just caught your edits about the `UITableView` and you're exactly correct! I am using an array of static strings which are copied from the name property of each crop. Again, still fairly new so I have no idea how I could've loaded in these values using a .plist, it's something I can look into. But for now I'm looking where I should place your demo function `- (NSMutableArray *)songs {}`... inside Crop.m or my detailviewcontroller? and just change the method name to crops?

Comment: Place the `NSMutableArray` method in your tableviewcontroller subclass. in the subclass header file add `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *crops;` and then below `@implementation` in the .m file add `@synthesize crops = _crops;` Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath you do Crop *crop = `[self.crops objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` and then `[[cell textLabel] setText:crop.name];` & yes, you still need your Crop.h/.m & a property for every key in your plist. Also, change your root key "Crops" from a dictionary to an array in your plist.

Comment: I'm actually working on a demo project for some friends who I'm teaching iOS dev to that has all of these concepts. I'll link it here when I'm done with it tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: Here's a link to the project I'm working on. I think it does everything you need it to, plus a bit more. Use it however you'd like. https://github.com/Jlawr3nc3/MusicLibraryiOS/zipball/v1

Comment: Haha thanks man. As for your expression result unused, you can combine that line and the line above into one with `Crop *thecrop = [[Crop alloc] initWithDictionary:currDict];`